# How do I invoke an Action on a new thread?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

In VB.NET, what is the syntax to start a new thread using a parameterless Action?

Comment: this question has already been discussed for sooo many times. there are soooo many articles, examples, etc. out there.

Comment: thefiloe, can you provide a link?

Comment: I get the impression that the previous commenters think this is a trivial question with a well-documented answer, but to me it is neither trivial nor well-documented, and I would be grateful for a helpful reply.

Comment: @Cyro How about `Dim t As New Thread(Sub() MessageBox.Show("No parameters here!")) : t.Start()`?

Comment: Bjørn, thank you for that example. However, I don't have a method like MessageBox; I have an object of type Action, and that seems to require a different syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"what is the syntax to start a new thread using a parameterless Action"*

Here are two examples:

**Example 1:**

```
Private Sub MyAction()
    [... Code goes here]
End Sub

Public Sub Test()
    Dim t As New Thread(AddressOf Me.MyAction)
    t.Start()
End Sub
```

**Example 2:**

```
Dim t As New Thread(Sub() [... Code goes here])
t.Start()
```

Comment: Oh, I finally get it. I can do this: `Dim t As New Thread(Sub() a.Invoke()) : t.Start()` Thank you for the help.

Comment: For clarity, I'll post this follow-up comment: Your examples show how to invoke a _Method_ in a new thread. My question was how to invoke an _Action_ on a new thread. Your solution is applicable because every Action has an Invoke method, but that detail was my particular stumbling block. Furthermore, correct me if I'm wrong, but this approach is VB specific, right?; in C#, I believe the ThreadStart constructor accepts an Action as an argument, and that would be a better way to create a new Thread from an Action.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of years too late but...use ThreadStart

```
Private _calculateThread As Thread

Private Sub CreateAndStartThread(ByVal threadDelegate As ThreadStart)

        _calculateThread = New Thread(threadDelegate)

        _calculateThread.Start()

End Sub
```

and somewhere else in your code

```
CreateAndStartThread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf Calculate))   

Private Sub Calculate()
  '... do your thread actions
end Sub
```